# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError while testing the net/smtp library

Tags: ruby, smtp

I am trying to send emails using the `net/smtp` library but I receive the following error message:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

The code I am using is an extract from Peter Cooper's `Beginning Ruby` book, modified to use SSL, as required by [yahoo servers](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail-for-desktop/pop-access-settings-instructions-yahoo-mail-sln4724.html?impressions=true):

```
require 'net/smtp'

message = %q{
    From: Private Person <me@privacy.net>
    To: myself <username@yahoo.com>
    Subject: SMTP e-mail test

    This is a test e-mail message.
}


smtp = Net::SMTP.new('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 587)
smtp.enable_ssl
smtp.start('example.org', 'username@yahoo.com', 'password', :login) do |s|
  s.send_message message, 'me@privacy.net', 'username@yahoo.com'
end
```

I tested the above code with `Ruby 2.3.1` and `Ruby 2.5.1` but I keep receiving the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Net::SMTP#enable_ssl` (which is an alias to `Net::SMTP#enable_tls)`, you are instructing the Ruby SMTP client to open a TLS tunnel as the very first step after connecting to the server. This requires the server to also support this on the used server port.

With Yahoos SMTP servers, they support this mode on port 465. With many other providers, you will see that they only support opportunistic TLS on port 587.

What happens there is that the client first starts with plain text SMTP and then negotiates with the server whether they support to update the connection to a TLS tunnel by using the `STARTTLS` command.

With `net/smtp` in Ruby, you can use [`Net::SMTP#enable_starttls`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html#method-i-enable_starttls) instead.

If you are not sure of the server supports STARTTLS and you want to gracefully fallbvack to plaintext transfer of your password and the email to the server, you can also use [`Net::SMTP#enable_starttls_auto`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html#method-i-enable_starttls_auto).

Thus, with Yahoo, you have two options:

- you can use `Net::SMTP#enable_tls` on port 465
- or you can use `Net::SMTP#enable_starttls` on port 587

Comment: With 'enable_tls` I receive `550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable (Net::SMTPFatalError)`, while using `enable_starttls` I receive `535 5.7.1 Authentication failed (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError)`

Comment: It seems, that you attempt to send mail **to** a Yahoo user, instead of **from** a Yahoo user. In that case, you have to use a different server (i.e. the mailserver of `privacy.net`) to send the mail to Yahoo. In general, when sending a mail via Yahoo's server, you have to authenticate as the sender which thus have to be a yahoo user.